# Set value in groups of 25

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to assign a value to a field in a database in groups of 25.  For example, the first 25 are assigned the value of 1, the next 25 a value of 2 etc.  I have tried to do this but I end up just looping through the whole thing giving everyone the same number.

Here is what I have so far...

```
$i = 1;
    while(($count > 0) && ($i < 10)){
        $sql = "UPDATE tbl_studentModules SET groupID = $i WHERE groupID = '' LIMIT 25";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
        $i++;
    }
```

Any help will be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: I'd use the OFFSET in combination with LIMIT

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_studentModules SET groupID = MOD(rowId, 25) WHERE groupID = ''";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

Try using `MOD` like above, it will assign every 25 users with a `groupID` ranging from 0 - 24 based on their `rowId` (assuming that is the field name of the row's ID).

No need for the `while` loop.

---

### Also important:

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that, unfortunately the unique ID in this table are varchar so the code doesn't work.  Thanks for the advice re the mysqli

Comment: @tatty27 please use a INTEGER id.... Do not rely on VARCHAR, it is not always reliable.

Comment: The database is from an external source that I am not allowed to change